# Square root of floor of square root of sum $\sqrt{\lfloor\sqrt{\left|x+y\right|}\rfloor}$

Tags: ceiling-and-floor-functions

Let $x,y$ $\in\mathbb{R}$ and $\lfloor x\rfloor = 10$ and $\lfloor y\rfloor = 14$.

Need to compute: $\sqrt{\lfloor\sqrt{\left|x+y\right|}\rfloor}= \; ?$

**MY IDEA**:

$$10\le x < 11$$

$$14\le y < 15$$

So $$24\le x+y < 26.$$

But then i don't know what to say about:

$$\lfloor\sqrt{|x+y|}\rfloor = \ldots$$

Because i don't get what is the use here for the absolute part: what his role here?

And how can i proceed?

Thanks.

Comment: The absolute value is a no-op there, you can ignore it. Under the constraints, what can $\lfloor \sqrt{x+y}\rfloor$ be?

Comment: i think that $4$?

Comment: Well, that or ...?

Comment: @feder Couldn't it be $5$ as well?

Comment: that or $5$? not sure how to show that, just by intuition

Comment: What constraints are placed on the problem? Does it have to be a single answer, or can it be a set of answers?

Comment: there are no constraints so to two solutions are right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you did so far is good.  Now justify these steps:
\begin{align*}
24 &\le x + y < 26 \\
24 &\le |x + y| < 26 \\
\sqrt{24} &\le \sqrt{|x + y|} < \sqrt{26} \\
4 &\le \left\lfloor{\sqrt{|x + y|}} \right\rfloor \le 5 \\
\sqrt{\left\lfloor{\sqrt{|x + y|}} \right\rfloor} &= 2 \text{ or } \sqrt{5}
\end{align*}
Indeed, as Ross Millikan states, there are two possible answers.  If you expected a single answer, you must not have written the question exactly right.

Comment: i expected two answers so thanks alot!:)

Answer (score 2):

Since you know $x+y > 0$, you know $|x+y|=x+y$ and you can remove the absolute value bars. They were just there to confuse you. You won't get a single answer.

Comment: so i can tell by the two inequalities that the values of $\lfloor \sqrt{x+y}\rfloor$ could be $4$ or $5$ so the answer would be $2$ or $\sqrt5$? but how can i show algebraic the the values can be $4$ or $5$?

Comment: Post this as a comment to his question, please.

Comment: @BrianJ.Fink Why?  It is common to answer questions with a hint rather than a full solution when that is deemed appropriate.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood the words "not...a single answer."

Comment: By the way, downvotes are for answers which are "not useful" (see the hovertext).

Comment: I tried to change my vote when I realized the true sense of what Ross was saying, @goos, but it was more than 6 minutes since I had cast it and the system wouldn't let me.

Comment: @BrianJ.Fink That has happened to me before too :)

Comment: @BrianJ.Fink I've made a trivial edit you should be able to remove the dv

Comment: @Goos I'll try to read the answer more closely next time. At first I thought he was saying the asker's question wasn't going to get answered at all.

Comment: @TooTone why did you remove my rewording?

Comment: Since my edit didn't take, I recommend changing the words "a single answer" to "just a single solution."

Comment: @BrianJ.Fink I didn't remove any wording. I was one of the 2 reviewers who rejected your proposed edit. I looked more closely to see if you were the OP (in which case I might have been more liberal in accepting the edit). In doing so I saw that you had tried to remove your downvote, so I made the trivial edit as a courtesy.

Comment: @TooTone the "trivial" edit restored the confusing language. What's an OP?

Comment: @BrianJ.Fink I didn't restore anything. I simply changed "\gt" to ">" which looks the same, in order to do you a favour. If you click on the "edited 13 mins ago" you will see the revision history of Ross' post which will confirm what I am saying. "OP" means "Original post" or "Original poster" or something similar. If you still don't understand it please can you post a question on meta, which is the right place to have a "meta-discussion".

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13260/discussion-between-brian-j-fink-and-tootone)

Comment: @BrianJ.Fink You are evidently the only one who found the language confusing.  I myself think that "You won't get a single answer" is quite clear and I admit am still a bit baffled at what is confusing about it.   In general edits should significantly improve a post and it didn't seem like your edit was doing much.

Comment: @Goos I think I took it as "not at all" rather than "not just one."

Comment: @goos maybe it's a regionalism.

Comment: @BrianJ.Fink Actually I know that meaning too, it just didn't occur to me at all.  Funny.  Well now I understand the source of confusion.  Regards

Comment: @BrianJ.Fink I finally understand what you meant. You meant "won't get a single answer" as in "if you don't hurry all the cake will be gone and you won't get a single piece" :) I think it's like one of those optical illusions where some people see it one way and other people see it another and it's hard to switch. I took my cue from the context of Ross' answer.

Comment: You can downvote for whatever reeason you want as long as it is not malicious.